# Vim Disable Syntastic For PHP Laravel Blade Files

Tags: php, laravel, vim, laravel-blade, syntastic

I use Vim for my PHP Laravel framework project.

I just installed Syntastic in my Vim but every time I open a blade file with Vim it gives me an error.

How do you disable Syntastic for blade files?

Blade is a Laravel specific template file.the extension is {filename}.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [vim-blade](https://github.com/jwalton512/vim-blade) then you can change the syntax checker for [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) using the following format:

```
let g:syntastic_<filetype>_checkers = ['<checker-name>']
```

So you will add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_blade_checkers = []
```

This will set all `blade` filetypes to use no checkers/linters (`[]`).

My guess however is that you do not have vim-blade installed so Vim and Syntastic are using the `php` filetype which is incorrect.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that Blade is a Laravel specific template file.the extension is {filename}.blade.php

Comment: Can you do `:set ft?` in a blade file? It should give you `blade` if you are using [vim-blade](https://github.com/jwalton512/vim-blade). If it gives you `php` then you do not have vim-blade installed correctly.